# AngularJS: Create mutliple factories from a service

Tags: angularjs

I want to create two separate instances from a service as in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yy7CrVcx5aW9pNFrSPxO?p=preview).

But it seems they share their members. What am I doing wrong?

```
angular.module("App", [])
.service("service", function() {
  var $this = this;
  this.number = 1;
  var getNumber = function() { return $this.number; }
  var setNumber = function(n) { $this.number = n; }
  this.build = function() {
    return {
      getNumber: getNumber,
      setNumber: setNumber
    }
  }
}
})

.factory('fac1', function(service) {
  return service.build();
})

.factory('fac2', function(service) {
  return service.build();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your service's `build` function create a new object and return the new object.

```
angular.module("App", [])
  .service("service", function() {
    var number = 0;
    var getNumber = function() { return this.number; }
    var setNumber = function(n) { this.number = n; }
    this.build = function() {
      var newObj = {};
      number += 1;
      newObj.number = number;
      newObj.getNumber = getNumber;
      newObj.setNumber = setNumber;
      return newObj;
    }
  })
```

As mentioned in another answer, both a **factory** provider and a **service** provider are singletons. In fact all AngularJS providers are singletons. But a singleton can serve as a "factory" that manufactures a class of objects.

Comment: Accessing object properties using [] is discouraged unless what you're putting inside the [] is a variable.

Comment: I get `cannot access member of undefined` when trying to use `this` in a function

Comment: @Wonko Don't use `$this`. Use `this` directly.

Comment: @georgeawg I did, no luck. It works fine in the plunkr, but not in my project. The only difference I can see is that I have a separate module. Any other clues what might be wrong?

Comment: @georgeawg why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're confused about how factories and services work.

Both factories and services are singletons, and moreover they both do basically the same thing. [More reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

`fac1` and `fac2` are using the same exact instance of `service` which means that the member sharing is actually the expected behavior.

Perhaps a solution to your problem would be creating a class inside of your service and returning a new instance of that in your build method.

Then you could do something like:

```
angular.module("App", [])
  .service("service", function() {
    var $this = this;

    function myClass() {
      this.number = 1;
    }
    myClass.prototype.getNumber = function() { return $this.number; };
    myClass.prototype.setNumber = function(n) { $this.number = n; }
    this.build = function() {
      return new myClass();
    }
  }
})
```

if you're unsure how classes work in javascript you could take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Also another thing to note. If all your factories are doing is returning your service then you probably don't need your factories at all. Just directly use your service's `build` method.